# Kann man sagen: "Mein Leben dauert 17 Jahre an"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure, standard-german

Ich bin beim Übersetzen eines Textes und bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich den Satz richtig formuliert habe.

> *Mein Leben dauert etwas länger als 17 Jahre an.*

Comment: Wie heißt denn der Satz im Original? Und warum bist du dir unsicher über deine Formulierung?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ohne Kontext (in welcher Situation wird der Satz geäußert) kann man hier nichts Endgültiges sagen. Außer dass der Satz  sehr ungewöhnlich ist.

Gehen wir ins Detail:

Rein syntaktisch-grammatisch ist der Satz richtig.

Inhaltlich versteht man ihn auch, jedenfalls auf Ebene der reinen sachlichen Aussage.

Jedoch: "Andauern" ist kein Verb, das man üblicherweise im Zusammenhang mit "Leben" verwendet.

Sätze, die in deutschsprachiger Kommunikation typischerweise vorkommen, ohne als komisch aufzufallen, sind zum Beispiel:

> Ich bin 17 Jahre alt.
>
> Ich bin gut 17 Jahre alt.
>
> Das Regenwetter dauert nun schon 17 Tage an.
>
> Das Regenwetter hält nun schon 17 Tage an.
>
> Wenn dieses Wetter noch länger andauert, gehe ich ein wie eine Primel.
>
> Diese Rede dauert nun schon fast zwei Stunden.
>
> Diese Rede dauert nun schon fast zwei Stunden an.
>
> Kannst du mir bitte nicht andauernd ins Gesicht pusten?
>
> Sie können hier noch nicht rein; die Veranstaltung dauert noch an.

Wie man aus den Beispielen erkennen kann, wird "andauern" vor allem dann verwendet, wenn man deutlich machen will, dass man das Dauern (oder Andauern) als lästig/unangenehm/störend empfindet.

In diesem Lichte klingt der Satz

> ? Mein Leben dauert mehr als 17 Jahre an.

gerade so, als wärest du dieses lästigen Lebens überdrüssig und wolltest ihm möglicherweise ein Ende setzen.

Wenn man dagegen ausdrücken will, dass einem etwas in seiner zeitlichen Länge gefällt, kann man etwa sagen:

> Das schöne Wetter hält nun schon zwei Wochen an, und der Wetterbericht sagt, dass es noch weiter anhalten wird. Juhu!

Dagegen würde

> ? Mein Leben hält nun schon 17 Jahre an.

auch wieder seltsam klingen. Es ist zwar deutlich, dass du dem Anhalten deines Lebens wohlwollend gegenüberstehst, aber gleichzeitig klingt es so, als hieltest du dein Leben für etwas Verderbliches, wie etwa ein Lebensmittel. Nun ist ein Leben ja, wie die Lebenserfahrung zeigt, in der Tat etwas Vergängliches (wenn auch nichts Verderbliches)<sup>1</sup>, doch scheint man in der menschlichen Kommunikation im Alltag Andeutungen dieser Vergänglichkeit aus dem Weg zu gehen, und darum fällt es wiederum als ungewöhnlich auf, wenn man sie doch andeutet, etwa durch die Wahl eines solchen Verbs.

---

<sup>1</sup> Ein philosophiler Kommentator/Editeur fügte hier ein "(Oder doch?)" ein. Ich danke für das Mitdenken, habe den Einschub aber wieder gelöscht, da er mir doch zu sehr von dritter Seite kam. Solche Zusatzgedanken können ja gut in den Kommentaren geäußert werden.

Comment: Mich interessiert mehr was die Fragezeichen vor den Sätzen ausdrücken sollen - ist das neu? Ein Grauimport?

Comment: @userunknown   Das ist eine Notation, die in der Sprachwissenschaft verbreitet ist. Man setzt ein Sternchen vor einen Ausdruck, um zu kennzeichnen, dass er nicht nachweisbar ist (aber z.B. sprachhistorisch angenommen werden muss), und ein Fragezeichen vor einen Ausdruck, den man für fragwürdig / möglicherweise falsch / zweifelhaft hält. Die <ironie>Jugend von heute</ironie> käme vermutlich mit "tags" besser zurecht. Die Funktion ist die gleiche. PS: Was ist ein Grauimport? (Ich kenne bisher nur das Grautier sowie graue Literatur.)

Comment: Oh, tatsächlich eine seriöse Notation? Dann ist es m.E. ok. Ein Grauimport ist etwas zwischen normalem Import und Schwarzimport. Rechtlich unklar, vielleicht noch nicht entschieden. Oftmals privat vorgenommene Einkäufe, die aber für den Handel (im kl. Umfang) bestimmt sind. Manche Elektronik wird beispielsweise nur auf regionalen Märkten angeboten. Oder Filme zu unterschiedlichen Zeiten veröffentlicht, je nach Region.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn weder der Kontext noch der Originalsatz vorliegen, ist das schwer zu beantworten.
Ist die erzählende Person tot und spricht als Geist? Dann würde ich das "an" weglassen, der Rest ginge (ob man es eleganter ausdrücken kann, hängt wiederum vom genauen Kontext ab).
Lebt die Person noch? Dann müsste es heißen "ich bin/war 17 Jahre alt".